# Deploying GWT application without using the google app engine

Tags: gwt, deployment

I created a project without using the "google app engine" (by unchecking the checkbox when I created the project).

When I debug the application, everything works fine but when I start deploying it to the webserver, I can't do any RPC calls (the onFailure method is executed).

Now my question is, if I have to add any *.jars into the tomcat server before I can deploy it.

Best regards, Stefan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can deploy your GWT project inside a WAR file. It works perfectly.

Doing a search in google you'll find multiple solutions, like this one: http://blog.elitecoderz.net/gwt-and-tomcat-create-war-using-eclipse-to-deploy-war-on-tomcat/2009/12/

Comment: That link has been dead since late 2014. For anyone still wanting to read the blog post (albeit without the images), use the [waybackmachine](http://web.archive.org/web/20141116220058/http://blog.elitecoderz.net/gwt-and-tomcat-create-war-using-eclipse-to-deploy-war-on-tomcat/2009/12).